# WebView onReceivedError detects no connection only at the beginning

Tags: android, kotlin

onCreate:

```
var browser:WebView = findViewById(R.id.browser)

browser.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
    override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html")
    }
}

browser.loadUrl("https://google.com")
```

If there is no Internet connection when app started, custom error page shows.

However if google.com loads in WebView and I click on links, and suddenly there is no Internet connection, default error page shows (ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED)

Can someone help how can I show custom error page both times?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think answer is in your error.html file.

so check this.

```
<!-- app/src/main/assets/www/error.html  -->
<body>
<div class="errorText">
    <div id="error-customer-guide"></div>
    <p>Press Refresh button</p>
    <p id="error-code"></p>

</div>
<div class="refreshBtn">
   <a href="https://service-main-domain"><button>Refresh</button></a>
</div>

</body>

<script>
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let errorCode = urlParams.get('errorCode');
    let errorDescription = urlParams.get('errorDescription');


    // make text as errorCode
    switch(errorCode) {
        case '-2': // net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED 
            document.getElementById('error-customer-guide').innerHTML = 'Check Internet State';
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById('error-customer-guide').innerHTML = 'you have got error (' + errorCode + ')';
            break;
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed error.html, but still same results.